# React and Vertical Responsive Design

Tags: html, css, reactjs, responsiveness

folks.  This one has me stumped.  I've looked through several posts and can't seem to find the exact same issue.  I'm creating a React app that mimics a Windows or Mac or Linux desktop UI.  In other words, I don't want the normal vertical (or horizontal) scroll bar to pop up in the web browser.  I found a great example on stackoverflow of how to accomplish this in CSS and flexbox.

```
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.box .row {
  border: 1px dotted #0313fc;
}

.box .row.header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.box .row.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

.box .row.footer {
  flex: 0 1 40px;
}


img {
  height: 95%;
  width: 95%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

The above CSS works perfectly in a vanilla HTML/CSS file.   When I resize the browser window vertically, the elements within are responsive.  When I do the exact same thing in the boilerplate create-react-app it fails.  The page is responsive *horizontally* but **not** vertically.  I removed all extra css files (like App.css) and just dumped the contents above into the index.css file, which I first cleared out.

Looking at the Styles in the Chrome browser window, all of the styles appear identical to the ones in the vanilla HTML.  I'm not sure why the browser isn't responsive in the vertical with this React project.  I'm afraid it's something in webpack or something else under the hood.

If anyone has an ideas about this, I'm all ears.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, right after I asked this, I found a solution.  After working with React for so many years, I forgot that it injects the code into the index HTML into a div with the id="root".  Once I applied the "box" CSS class to that element, it worked as expected!  So now the question is: is there a way to inject this class into the HTML through React? :)